# for loop issues, ls not working right

Tags: command-line, perl

I have a code that has to be run through Ubuntu. When my code reaches filelist, instead of giving all of the subfolders within the filelist, it gives the same list as from the subjectlist... why is this happening? Here is the organization of my folders: Newdata, subjectnames, SEFolders, & files to process or remove. Ubuntu is also not recognizing SE, and this is how those subfolders are named e.g. "SE13" Instead of NotePad, Perl was used.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$subj_path = "/mnt/c/Users/alicj/Desktop/NEWData";

chdir "$subj_path";

@subj_list=ls -d *;

print "The current directory has the following subjects @subj_list \n";

foreach(@subj_list)

{
chomp;
$subj_name=$_;
print "Working on subject $subj_name \n";

$current_path = "$subj_path"."$subj_name"."/";
chdir "$current_path";

print "Starting Reconstruction in the current directory >> $current_path \n";

@file_list=`ls -d SE*`;
print "The current directory has the following files @file_list \n";

foreach(@file_list)
{

chomp;
$file_name=$_;
print "Working on folder $file_name \n";

$file_path = "$current_path"."$file_name"."/";
chdir "$file_path";

`rm -r *.nii`;
`rm -r *.json`;

`dcm2nii -b ~/.dcm2nii/dcm2nii.ini IM*`;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of your script did not come through clearly, but it would be helpful if it checked for errors in a few place.

You can use perl's file matching - see perldoc for more info:

```
perldoc -f glob
```

perhaps expanded with list filtering the return from the glob with grep (here for files):

```
grep { -f $_ } <SE*>
```

Also consider:

```
perldoc -f system
```

to spawn off the `dcm2nii` command:

```
system("dcm2nii -b ~/.dcm2nii/dcm2nii.ini ".join(" ",<IM*>))
```

You also didn't ask for a code review, but I'd caution against blindly executing rm commands inside back quotes (use unlink instead of forking off a subshell and running rm) see:

```
perldoc -f unlink
```

I was also going to suggest enabling perl's warnings and strict checking to the top, but that might more than needed

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```